# How do I use a custom SSLContextFactory in a Restlet application running on Jetty?

Tags: java, ssl, restlet

I'm trying to use Restlet's ClientResource to connect using HTTPS to a server that uses a self-signed certificate. I have this working using a stand-alone application that just uses ClientResource and my custom SSLContextFactory added as an attribute and code for it can be seen here:

https://github.com/pixelatedpete/selfsignedexample

When I use the same classes (DynamicTrustManager and SelfSignSslSocketFactory) in a more complex Restlet application (with the same pom as above) that uses Restlet to provide a REST API served via Jetty my custom SSLContextFactory is no longer being used.

I add it to the ClientResource context as above but I never see any of the log messages suggesting that the SSLContextFactory provided to ClientResource is passed down to the underlying httpclient.

If I rewrite using HttpClient directly rather than ClientResource:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(cr.getReference().toString());
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(...);
DynamicTrustManager tm = new DynamicTrustManager(..., cert);
SelfSignTrustSslContextFactory scf = (SelfSignTrustSslContextFactory) 
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSslcontext(scf.createSslContext()).build();
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
```

things work again.

Is this something anyone else has come across and can point out what I suspect is a very obvious thing I'm missing?

Nb. Tried again using Tomcat and get the same issue

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Also tried injecting the SslContextFactory (we're using Guice here) but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so finally figured it out - I was missing the Client bit:

```
Client client = new Client(crCtx, Protocol.HTTPS);
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("https://example.com");
clientResource.setNext(client);
```